# Qooxdoo sound button on/off doesnt work

Tags: javascript, createjs, qooxdoo, soundjs

I catch button in the code: `this.buttons.Sound.addListener("pressed", this.__sound, this);`

And write function, but then I push button sound off/on they didn't work.

```
__sound: function(){
  if (this.buttons.Sound.isEnabled()){
     createjs.Sound.volume = 1;
   } else {
     createjs.Sound.volume = 0;
   }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

After this all work

```
__sound: function(){

if (this.buttons.Sound.isEnabled()){
createjs.Sound.setVolume(1);
} else {
createjs.Sound.setVolume(0);
}
},
```

Comment: What version of SoundJS are you using? The getter/setter property was added in 0.6.1, whereas you had to use the `setVolume` method in previous versions.

Comment: I used 0.6.1 version.